# Using onClick() function on <Link> in responsive react-sidebar package does not works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, react-sidebar

react-sidebar https://github.com/balloob/react-sidebar is made to work with `<a href>` tags so whenever I click on the link the page refreshes, sidebar closes and scroll is restored. But I want to use react-router `<Link>` instead of href. It does not restore the scroll and sidebar won't close in small screen by itself.

(1) for closing: I tried to use `onClick(toggleOpen)` on `<Link>` to toggle sidebar which closes it but does not routes to the page.
(2) for scroll restore: I tried to use `window.scrollToTop(0,0)`, it doesn't work either.

Here is the code:

material_title_panel.js

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const styles = {
  root: {
    fontFamily:
      '"HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif',
    fontWeight: 300
  }
};
const Title = (props) => {
  const rootStyle = props.style
    ? { ...styles.root, ...props.style }
    : styles.root;

  return (
    <div style={rootStyle}>
      <div style={styles.header}>{props.title}</div>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

Title.propTypes = {
  style: PropTypes.object,
  title: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.object]),
  children: PropTypes.object
};

export default Title;
```

sidebar_content.js

```
import Title from "./title";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Nav } from "react-bootstrap";

const SidebarContent = (props) => {
  const { toggleOpen, open } = props;
  return (
    <>
      <Title title="Menu">
        <Nav defaultActiveKey="/home" className="flex-column ">
          <Nav.Item>
            {/*  href to restore scroll and close sidebar, but refreshes page */}
            {/* Link for desired behaviour but no scroll restoration and sidebar doesnot closes*/}
            <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/home" onClick={toggleOpen}>
              {open ? "Home" : "close"}
            </Nav.Link>
          </Nav.Item>

          <Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/resource">
              Resource Requisition
            </Nav.Link>
          </Nav.Item>
        </Nav>
      </Title>
    </>
  );
};
export default SidebarContent;
```

App.js

```
const mql = window.matchMedia(`(min-width: 768px)`);

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      docked: mql.matches,
      open: false
    };

    this.mediaQueryChanged = this.mediaQueryChanged.bind(this);
    this.toggleOpen = this.toggleOpen.bind(this);
    this.onSetOpen = this.onSetOpen.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    mql.addListener(this.mediaQueryChanged);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    mql.removeListener(this.mediaQueryChanged);
  }

  onSetOpen(open) {
    this.setState({ open });
  }

  mediaQueryChanged() {
    this.setState({
      docked: mql.matches,
      open: false
    });
  }

  toggleOpen(ev) {
    this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });

    if (ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
    }
  }
  render() {
    const sidebar = (
      <SidebarContent toggleOpen={this.toggleOpen} open={this.state.open} />
    );
    const contentHeader = (
      <div>
        {!this.state.docked && (
          <a onClick={this.toggleOpen} href="#/">
            {" "}
            ={" "}
          </a>
        )}
      </div>
    );
    const sidebarProps = {
      sidebar,
      docked: this.state.docked,
      open: this.state.open,
      onSetOpen: this.onSetOpen
    };

    return (
      <>
        <Sidebar {...sidebarProps}>
          <Title title={contentHeader}>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/resource" component={Resource} />
            </Switch>
          </Title>
        </Sidebar>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

detailed code in sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-forked-01psh?file=/src/sidebar_content.js

Comment: The sandbox you added doesn't compile; also not sure if the question is really clear, as I cannot run the example.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: have you tried to parse the event in the callback and do an `event.preventDefault()`, as anchor tags do have a default click behavior? Is there also a specific reason as to why you chose to go with an anchor tag, and not some other element? In case you need something specific from an anchor tag, you can always style the other elements to be whatever you want, and you'll omit the whole problem of having to deal with anchor tags default, interactive behavior.

Comment: using <Link> for routing inside app